# how do I avoid tmp file when creating alias in H2

Tags: java, h2

I have H2 db that has the alias as this

```
CREATE ALIAS TO_TIMESTAMP as '
import java.text.*;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Date;
@CODE
    Timestamp to_timestamp(String dateText, String oraclePattern) throws Exception {
        String javaDatePattern = null;
        if (oraclePattern.equals("fmMMfm/fmDDfm/YYYY fmHH12fm:MI:SS.FF AM")) {
            javaDatePattern = "MM/dd/yyyy";
        }
        if (javaDatePattern==null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unhandled oracle date pattern");
        }

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(javaDatePattern);

        Date date= sdf.parse(dateText);
        return new Timestamp(date.getTime());
    }
';
```

however, when I run the junit test that uses this alias I keep getting error

```
; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: IO Exception:
 "java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/tmp/org/h2/dynamic/TO_TIMESTAMP.java 
(Permission denied)"; "/var/tmp/org/h2/dynamic/TO_TIMESTAMP.java";
```

It works fine on eclipse alone but failed when I ran this on unix. 
I was wondering how do I prevent h2 from create tmp file (generated java) in unix in that directory or to compile without above error?